# Как реализовать выдачу большого кол-ва элементов через ajax с пагинацией в bitrix

Tags: ajax, битрикс, pagination

Сайт на CMS Bitrix.

Есть некий список новостей, который выводится компонентом news с пагинацией. Пользователь посылает некий запрос (например, поиск по новостям, или фильтр), запрос обрабатывается на ajax, и полученные данные мне нужно показать вместо первоначального списка.

**Проблема:** если элементов в результате слишком много, как мне через js сымитировать битриксовую пагинацию и просматривать результаты без перезагрузки страницы? Подскажите правильное решение, не могу представить себе в голове, как это сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется кнопка ПОКАЗАТЬ ЕЩЁ вместо пагинации
https://github.com/studiofact/wiki-bitrix/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%97%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%AC-%D0%95%D0%A9%D0%81-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8